# MS Word. Changing the text color depending on checked/unchecked checkbox

Tags: checkbox, ms-word, textcolor

I'm using MS Word 2016.

Is it possible to implement changing the text color from black to red depending on checked/unchecked checkbox?

Comment: A lot of people won't download random files someone links here. You should really have all necessary info included in your question.

Comment: Yes. It is possible. It is not simple. I believe your question would be better posted in a non-programming forum. This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word  or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums. At least there, you can get a better idea of how Word would approach such a problem. Note that conditional formatting is not a strength of Word.

Comment: Charles, thank you for links.

Comment: Since this will require a fairly simple coding, I can't see why any competent coder would say «It is not simple» or why anyone would say «your question would be better posted in a non-programming forum». StackOverflow is indeed the correct place to post such a question! As for the question itself, you haven't told us anything about what type of checkbox you're using or how the text to be processed would be identified.

Comment: See, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/23848-conditional-formatting-word-dropdown-list.html & https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/16505-change-color-according-dropdown-selection.html Both sets of code are for dropdowns, but the principles are the same.

Comment: @macropod I'm using regular checkboxes provided by MS Word 2016 in Developer tab:
Developer | Controls | Check Box Content Control
Hope this is clarify the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following macro assumes you're using a Checkbox Content Control titled 'Checkbox1' and, for the text to be re-formatted, a Rich Text Content Control titled 'ColorText':

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal CCtrl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim Clr As Long
With CCtrl
  Select Case .Title
    Case "Checkbox1"
        Select Case .Checked
          Case True: Clr = wdRed
          Case Else: Clr = wdAuto
        End Select
      ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("ColorText")(1).Range.Font.ColorIndex = Clr
  End Select
End With
End Sub
```

The code goes in the 'ThisDocument' code module of the document or its template.

Comment: thank you for help. Your code works perfectly as I expected. Though I have modified it in order to color the checkbox itself too.
`ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("ColorText")(1).Range.Font.ColorIndex = Clr
ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Checkbox1")(1).Range.Font.ColorIndex = Clr`